# All HTML Pages are not converting to PDF with SelectPdf

Tags: c#, pdf

I am using the following code to convert large HTML content to PDF using iTextSharp SelectPDF. None of the HTML pages are correctly converted. The data vanishes after 6 pages into the PDF.

```
public static void CreatePDFFromHTMLFile(string HtmlStream, string FileName)
    {
        try
        {
            // read parameters from the webpage
            string htmlString = HtmlStream;
            string baseUrl = "";
            string pdf_page_size = "A4";
            PdfPageSize pageSize = (PdfPageSize)Enum.Parse(typeof(PdfPageSize),
                pdf_page_size, true);
            string pdf_orientation = "Portrait";
            PdfPageOrientation pdfOrientation =
                (PdfPageOrientation)Enum.Parse(typeof(PdfPageOrientation),
                pdf_orientation, true);
            int webPageWidth = 1024;
            int webPageHeight = 0;
            HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
            // set converter options
            converter.Options.PdfPageSize = pageSize;
            converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = pdfOrientation;
            converter.Options.WebPageWidth = webPageWidth; 
            converter.Options.WebPageHeight = webPageHeight;
            // create a new pdf document converting an url
            PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlString, baseUrl);
            doc.Save(FileName);
            doc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Tracing.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no `HtmlToPdf` class in iTextSharp, hence your question should not be labeled as an iText question. I have no idea what `HtmlToPdf` is about (and I'm the original developer of iText; if such a class existed in iTextSharp, I'd know). Also: don't expect an answer if you don't share the HTML.

Comment: Looks like SelectPDF to me: http://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/demo/convert-html-code-to-pdf.aspx I will update the tags, can you approve my edit Bruno?

Comment: Maybe the OP is a current user of SelectPDF but isn't happy with it? Maybe they want to switch to iText and are probing the technical support?

Answer (score 3):

That is happening because you are using the community edition of SelectPdf which is free with the limitation that you can only convert to pdf up to 5-6 pages long, if you need more than that you will need to use the non-free one instead from here https://selectpdf.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using SelectPdf community edition. According to SelectPdf (http://selectpdf.com/community-edition/), the free version is limited to 5 pages.

If you want to convert longer pages, you need to use the commercial edition, but that is not free.